# Is there a term for operations that are only defined for some members of a set?

Tags: matrices, universal-algebra

For example, matrix multiplication is only defined for certain combinations of matrices in the set of all matrices. So, I can't call the combination of the set of all matrices and matrix multiplication a group. Even though I can talk about it being closed and non-commutative. Is it called something else?

Comment: This is close to the notion of "partial function."

Comment: You can't even call the set of all $2\times2$ matrices a group under matrix multiplication, since they don't all have inverses.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for partial functions: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function